# jQuery randomize picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery

I am making a photo gallery using jQuery and I want to have a button to display a random picture taken from the ones in the album. This picture should change every time the user clicks on the button. I have this code but every time I press the button I have the div#images fulling with the images instead of each one every time.

```
<script>
        $('button').on('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('images.json', function(data) {
                imageList = data;               
            });
            $('#images').append('<img src=' + imageList[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageList.length) + 1].img_src + '>').;  
        });
</script>
```

As you can see I read the images from a JSON file and randomize from 1 to the length of the file. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) Do you want to clear the images before you display another one at the end? 2) Why are you realoading all the image data every time? Don't you only need it once?

Comment: @PeterOlson I did it actually. Thank you for mentioning this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the image div before adding the new image otherwise the images will keep adding.

```
  <script>
            $('button').on('click', function() {
                $.getJSON('images.json', function(data) {
                    imageList = data;  
                    //Also, move the code inside getJson(). getJson is asynchronous.
                    //Clear the images HTML
                    $('#images').empty();
                    $('#images').append('<img src=' + imageList[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageList.length) + 1].img_src + '>').;               
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Just wondering : Why don't you retrieve 1 random image via json call, instead of fetching all the images and then choosing one (Write the randomization code at the server) ?

Comment: `.empty()` is the idiomatic way in jQuery to do the equivalent of `.html('')`.

Comment: In regards to your edit - if its a small list of images, `images.json` looks like static file, he could also atleast just load the list once.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. Your answer now makes sense to me. +1ing

Answer (score 2):

Does the JSON data change?  Otherwise, why do a request everytime?  Separating the `rand` and `image` vars below isn't necessary, but might be easy to read for others later.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    if ( typeof imageList == 'undefined' || !imageList.length )
    {
        $.getJSON('images.json', function(data) {
            imageList = data;
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageList.length) + 1;
            var image = $('<img />').attr('src', imageList[ rand ].img_src );
            $('#images').html( image );
        });  
    }
    else
    {
       var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageList.length) + 1;
       var image = $('<img />').attr('src', imageList[ rand ].img_src );
       $('#images').html( image );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close the image tag as well as clear the existing image

```
<script>
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('images.json', function(data) {
            imageList = data;               
        });
        $('#images').html("");
        $('#images').append('<img src=' + imageList[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageList.length) + 1].img_src + '/>');  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The self-closing `/>` is not necessary. It is expressly not required in HTML5, and is only necessary if he is writing to validate with XHTML.